# Converting MySQL query that has a GROUP BY to MSSQL query

Tags: mysql, sql-server

Hi I'm trying to convert my MySQL database to MSSQL one so what I'm doing is changing most of my queries. Then I encountered the GROUP BY problem in the MSSQL so I was stuck in this part.

```
tbl_assign role:
tar_id int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
tar_auth int NOT NULL,
tar_role varchar(255) NOT NULL,
tar_group int NOT NULL,
tar_division int NOT NULL,
tar_add varchar(255) NOT NULL,
tar_edit varchar(255) NOT NULL,
tar_view varchar(255) NOT NULL,
tar_delete varchar(255) NOT NULL,
tar_updated_date datetime NOT NULL,
tar_updated_by int NOT NULL,
tar_owner_id int NOT NULL,
tar_assign_date datetime NOT NULL,
tar_is_deleted tinyint NOT NULL

tbl_user:
u_id int NOT NULL,
u_uname varchar(255) NOT NULL,
u_pword varchar(255) NOT NULL,
u_fname varchar(255) NOT NULL,
u_mname varchar(255) NOT NULL,
u_lname varchar(255) NOT NULL,
u_spark_id varchar(255) NOT NULL,
u_email varchar(255) NOT NULL,
u_mobile decimal(11,0) NOT NULL,
u_address varchar(255) NOT NULL,
u_div int NOT NULL,
u_group int NOT NULL,
u_role int NOT NULL,
u_updated_by int NOT NULL,
u_updated_date datetime NOT NULL,
u_reg_date datetime NOT NULL,
is_active tinyint NOT NULL,
is_online tinyint NOT NULL,
u_photo varchar(MAX) NOT NULL
```

Sample data

```
tbl_user:
u_id - 20
u_uname - USERNAME
u_pword - *********
u_fname - Fname
u_mname - Mname
u_lname - Lname
u_spark_id - 1
u_email - email@sample.com
u_mobile - 0
u_address - Address
u_div - 0
u_group - 0
u_role - 0
u_updated_by - 1
u_updated_date - 2015-07-30 00:00:00
u_reg_date - 2015-04-08 00:00:00
is_active - 1
is_online - 1
u_photo - 0

tbl_assign_role:
tar_id - 264
tar_auth - 2
tar_role - 44
tar_group - 1
tar_division - 1
tar_add - 1-1-1-1-1-1-1-0-0-1-0-1-1-0-0
tar_edit - 1-1-1-1-1-1-1-0-0-1-0-1-1-0-0
tar_view - 1-1-1-1-1-1-1-0-0-1-0-1-1-0-0
tar_delete - 0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0
tar_updated_date - 2015-04-08 11:51:50.000
tar_updated_by - 17
tar_owner_id - 20
tar_assign_date - 2015-04-08 11:51:50.000
tar_is_deleted - 0
```

The tbl_assign_role has 9 more entries that has the same owner_id but different in the other columns.

MySQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_user 
JOIN tbl_assign_role ON tbl_user.u_id = tbl_assign_role.tar_owner_id 
WHERE is_active = 1 
AND u_id !=1 
AND tar_is_deleted = 0 
GROUP BY tbl_assign_role.tar_owner_id
ORDER BY tbl_user.u_updated_date DESC
```

Result of MySQL query has only one row. It will give the first entry on the tbl_assign_role that has the same owner_id.

MSSQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_user 
JOIN tbl_assign_role ON tbl_user.u_id = tbl_assign_role.tar_owner_id 
WHERE is_active = 1 
AND u_id !=1 
AND tar_is_deleted = 0 
ORDER BY tbl_user.u_updated_date DESC
```

Result of MSSQL query has ten rows. It will give all the result of the tbl_assign_role that has the same owner_id.

How can I achieve the same result in the MySQL query?

Comment: I don't think you can use `SELECT *` with `GROUP BY` in MS SQL. Try specifying the column, and use the `GROUP BY` in MS SQL query.

Comment: I tried that but it gave me the same result.

Comment: Distinct should give you a single result, if you have a table that has a column & it has a New value; Then you something else. Can you post a sample out put that is and is not expected.

Comment: What result do you expect? MySQL group by is just picking an indeterminate row in this example. SQL Server is not going to let you do this. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-handling.html

Comment: My expected output is that it will only return 1 row. But I have 10 rows in tbl_assign_role that will match because  my 'WHERE' statement is that it will match the owner_id. So what will happen is that it returns 10 rows but I only need the first output.

Comment: First do note MySQL is lenient on not allowing non-aggregated columns from not being specified in `GROUP BY` clause This actually goes against ANSI syntax, the gold standards of SQL that most dialects try to follow. So, MSSQL is actually following the rule.  But set MySQL's ANSI mode on and above query will not work. As for you issue, does MSSQL return repeating rows? Try adding `SELECT TOP 1 * FROM tbluser...`

Comment: @Parfait I'm trying to output 1 row per username. I have other username so that won't produce the output that I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For many databases, and MS SQL Server is one, it is not possible to specify just a single column in the GROUP BY clause, but use the wildcard for all columns in the select clause. MySQL is the odd one here, it does allow this.

So, the message is simple. You MUST specify the non-aggregating columns in the GROUP BY clause. No exceptions.

You might want to consider use of **ROW_NUMBER() OVER([partition by ...] order by ...)** if you are really just wanting to return a single row per tar_owner_id.

```
SELECT
      *
FROM (
      SELECT
            *
          , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY tbl_assign_role.tar_owner_id 
                               ORDER BY tbl_user.u_updated_date DESC) AS rn
      FROM tbl_user
      JOIN tbl_assign_role
            ON tbl_user.u_id = tbl_assign_role.tar_owner_id
      WHERE is_active = 1
      AND u_id != 1
      AND tar_is_deleted = 0
) AS D
WHERE D.rn = 1
ORDER BY <<some column(s)>>
OFFSET 10 ROWS
FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY
```

Comment: This works. I'm also adding an offset to output only 10 at a time. Where would I put this `OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY`

Comment: it depends, what version of mssql is it? please always include versions no matter which dbms it is

Comment: I'm using the 2012 version.

Comment: It says that It there is an incorrect syntax near `OFFSET`

Comment: did you read the reference given? seriously, it pays to read the manual, because we volunteers don't write production ready code, we just answer questions (**" Where would I put this "** was the extra question)

Comment: That would output an error because it is outside the select query

Comment: Don't follow. What is "that"? Did you read https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg699618(v=sql.110).aspx ? there are examples there for you to follow. I have supplied a well proven technique that answers your question but you also then wanted to extend the question on pagination, I supplied some relevant information and a manual page for your reference. I don't have a warranty agreement with you to provide production ready sql, I just volunteer some answers. Not quite sure what you are expecting.

Comment: It gave an error in the `ORDER BY` part in the bottom. it says **The multi-part identifier "tbl_user.u_updated_date" could not be bound.**

Comment: goodness. did you research what that means at all instead of just assuming I will fix your errors? the tablename tbl_user is no longer valid in the order by clause. Look at the query. Do you notice **where D.rn=1** ? what is that "D"? you need to learn how to fix this yourself. (i.e. I am doing you a favour by not fixing it)